# adding a "at" in the timedate stamp

Tags: php

I got this:

```
<?php echo date("F j, Y at g:ia", strtotime(strtoupper(stripslashes($row['date'])))); ?>
```

I formatted everything correctly, but when I add "at" in, it shows:

```
April 3, 2014 am30 10:35am
```

I want it to show as April 3, 2014 @ 10:34am any ideas?

Comment: Can't add these on the first parameter like `F j, Y @ g:ia`? If its not working, try to escape this: `F j, Y \@ g:ia`

Comment: You want to show `@` while passing `at`. It's weird

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape those characters.

```
echo date("F j, Y \a\\t g:ia"
```

or for the `@`

```
echo date("F j, Y \@ g:ia"
```

Comment: it doesn't show the "T" just the "a" any idea why this is happening?

Comment: [PHP date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) - states that `a` is _`Lowercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem (am or pm)`_ and `t` is _`Number of days in the given month (28 through 31)`_ . To clarify your answer so that OP understands.

Comment: @TrippedStackers I apologize. You need to double-escape `\t` because it has a special use. [here's a working example](http://ideone.com/fork/b7XBBG)

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping 'at' like so:

```
"F j, Y \a\t g:ia"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `a` and double escape the `t`

```
<?php
echo date("F j, Y \a\\t g:ia", strtotime(strtoupper(stripslashes($row['date']))));
?>
```

Escaping means to use the `\` character.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? Escape @ by using backslash .

> php echo date("F j, Y \@ g:ia",
>   strtotime(strtoupper(stripslashes($row['date']))));

Really? Aprile? Not April?

Comment: it was a typo, calm down

Comment: Got it. Be more attentive next time.

Comment: Sidenote: Aprile is italian for April.

Comment: That's cute but he said that it's a typo.

Comment: LOL, silly me. Here I was looking all over the page to see where the OP wrote that, and it was here in your answer; duh. Sorry, oh well, you've learned how to say April in Italian now ;-) Cheers @kimbarcelona Edit: Your answer was partially right, so I will +1